# SSIS Package stuck "Validating Excel Source" in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, import-from-excel

I have a quarterly update package that I run from the backend of our system that uses an Excel (2007 format) document as a data source. The package stages the data from the Excel document to a table within the database, where it is processed and loaded in the production system.

Today, I received the Q2 update for April 2015, and attempted to run the new file into the staging system through Visual Studio as I have in the past. But for some reason today, VS / SSIS appears to be stuck "Validating Excel Source". I've let it sit for up to 10 minutes, before having to kill my Visual Studio instance through Task Manager.

The source document is small and relatively uncomplicated on 6 columns and less that 300 Kb in size, so I can't understand the validation issue all of a sudden. It appears to be the same excel version and format as my previous runs.

This package has been untouched for the better part of year, only having to change a series of parameters for each quarterly run.

I've deleted the connection managers and excel components from the package and recreated them but still appear to have the same issue. I've also recreated the source document.

I attempted tp disabled the DelayValidation and ValidateExternalMetaData properties, in hopes that it might give me a meaningful error dialogue, but have yet to get past the "Validating Excel Source" message.

Any input would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running Visual Studio as an administrator?

Comment: running as administrator had no effect on the issue. It appears to have been an Excel Office Driver issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I appear to have found a resolution to the issue.

It appears that a recent update to my installed Office suite altered the driver for Excel on my machine.

The following articles helped me resolve the issue, but as it turned out I needed to reinstall the Office 2007 System Driver: Data Connectivity Components...(linked in the 2nd article)

Once installed I was able to reopen my solution and view the Excel document.

Thank you for the assistance.

[Using Excel 2012 file in Excel Connection Manager](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/43f5b285-4f07-49db-91e2-e89b68ccfd64/using-excel-2012-file-in-the-excel-connection-manager)

[How to fix errors: "the 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"](http://ssis-ssdt.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/how-to-fix-errors-microsoft.html)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the excel file that the connection manager is looking for from the directory that it is pointing to. Once you do that the Validation of the Excel source should fail when it can not find the file it is looking for. This should allow you to get into the package and set Delay Validation = True in the properties.

The package validates the excel connection manager the same as it would any other OLE DB connection manager. It confirms connection and then runs your statement to validate the return of data. If you take away its source it should flame out quickly.

I have found that background processing on your machine can block this validation or processing of the request the same as a priority query might in SQL. If you machine is in a state with a number of priority tasks running this validation is put on the back burner and can and will take forever. In cases like this the connection used to the source being used to validate with either disconnect or timeout and it is not handled in the UI so it just hangs and locks up.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it tried doing as you said however it doesn't appear to have resolved my issue.  I am leaning towards this being an issue with the Excel drivers that are installed, as it now appears to affect any Excel document I am trying to use as a source in my SSIS packages.

Comment: That will do it. That was going to be my next suggestion as there is not a really good error handling system with the jet or ace connection managers they just tend to crap out and lock up